# OS X Lion doesn't copy some files between different folder

Tags: osx-lion

yesterday I installed my Lion, worked fine !

Today I downloaded few mp3 files from internet using Chrome, they went to the Downloads folder.

The first problem is when I go to the folder, on the column Kind these mp3 are tagged as Document ... why ? my old mp3 that I downloaded before Lion are tagged as MP3 Audio.

The other problem, when I select any of these downloaded (or all of them) hit command+c, go to my Desktop and hit command+v, Lion makes the sound of copying files, but the new icon just blinks and the file vanishes from Desktop.

What is going on ?

If I drag the file to the Desktop, it goes without any problem, but Copy & Paste to any place the files won't go at all !

Comment: What happens with other kinds of files downloaded using Chrome; the same files downloaded with a different browser (Safari, Firefox); copying from the Terminal or in a different file manager (such as Forklift or Path Finder); when you copy using drag and drop, holding down the Option key?

Answer (score 1):

This is so far becoming a more and more widespread problem for a lot of new osx 10.7 Lion users.
It appears to be a Finder issue, and there is at this point no easy workaround.
But there are ways to overcome the problem.

There appears to be no problem when copying via the terminal, using command cp.

When copying between computers on a network, i advise to enable ssh, and use a program like Cyberduck (freeware) to copy files using the sFTP protocol.

I am using both approaches to ensure a stable copying and have seen no problems, except the obvious that it is a pain in the A** to do it this way.

There a numerous discussions about this on the web f.ex. https://discussions.apple.com/message/15747540#15747540

Thomas